# Failing to send model with abstract list property throught jquery ajax

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working with MVC asp.net 4 and jquery. 
Here is my problem:
I have following Model:

```
public class PledgeModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public IList<AbstractAsset> Assets { get; set; }
}
```

One if its properties is List of objects, each of them inheriting abstract class:

```
public abstract  class AbstractAsset
{
    public string commetns { get; set; }
}


public class RealEstateAsset:AbstractAsset
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
}
public class TransportationAsset : AbstractAsset
{
    public string LicenseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

}

Here is my "Get"  Action  code:

```
       //init new Pledge  
        PledgeModel pledge=new PledgeModel();
        pledge.name = "Moses";
        pledge.Assets=new List<AbstractAsset>();

        RealEstateAsset realEstateAsset = new RealEstateAsset();
        TransportationAsset transportationAsset=new TransportationAsset();

        realEstateAsset.CityId = 1;
        transportationAsset.LicenseNumber = "7654321";

        pledge.Assets.Add(realEstateAsset);
        pledge.Assets.Add(transportationAsset);


        ViewBag.Pledge = pledge;
```

When i get the pledge model in Json on the View i'm getting following json:

{"name":"Moses","Assets":[{"CityId":1,"commetns":null},
   {"LicenseNumber":"7654321","commetns":null}]};

IF i'm trying to send the whole model and its assets list in ajax callback:

```
                              var ajaxOptions = {
                                type: 'post',
                                url: 'Home/TryInsertPledge',
                                contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8;",
                                dataType:'json',
                                data:JSON.stringify({pledge:pledge}),
                                success: function(data) {
                                    alert('success');
                                },
                                error: function() {
                                    alert('error');
                                }
                              };
                              $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

"post" action:

```
   [HttpPost]
   public JsonResult TryInsertPledge(PledgeModel pledge)
   {


       return Json(new {sucess = "success"});
   }
```

For some reason i got error (If you click the red error of request in chrome developer tool) 'Cannot create an abstract class'

But if assets list is empty -i got my pledge correctly

Please help

Thanks

Comment: Is your jQuery ajax hitting the controller action ?

Comment: In case i comment all the setting assets list stuff -yes

Comment: give an id to your form and then try this in data attribute                                                  data:$('#formname').serialize();

Answer (score 0):

In your Ajax call what is pledge being generated from?  If its a form you need to make sure that all of the properties of each abstract asset are somehow included in the form. If you don't want these to be input fields that your user can edit set the type on the input field to hidden.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, meanwhile i'm testing without inputs (the json i got comes from viewbag:var pledge = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Pledge)) );)

Comment: Try data:pledge, in your Ajax call assuming pledge is already ajax

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to http://maciejlis.com/asp-mvc-3-model-binder-with-abstract-class-support/
I got the solution to my problem:

I have added customBinder (completely copied from the maciejlis blog)
This custom binder mapping the asset object according to type property(which must be exactly as asset classs name)

```
    public class EnhancedDefaultModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override object CreateModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, Type modelType)
        {
            Type type = modelType;
            if (modelType.IsGenericType)
            {
                Type genericTypeDefinition = modelType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
                if (genericTypeDefinition == typeof(IDictionary<,>))
                {
                    type = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(modelType.GetGenericArguments());
                }
                else if (((genericTypeDefinition == typeof(IEnumerable<>)) || (genericTypeDefinition == typeof(ICollection<>))) || (genericTypeDefinition == typeof(IList<>)))
                {
                    type = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(modelType.GetGenericArguments());
                }
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            }
            else if (modelType.IsAbstract)
            {
                string concreteTypeName = bindingContext.ModelName + ".Type";
                var concreteTypeResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(concreteTypeName);

                if (concreteTypeResult == null)
                    throw new Exception("Concrete type for abstract class not specified");

                type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(t => t.IsSubclassOf(modelType) && t.Name == concreteTypeResult.AttemptedValue);

                if (type == null)
                    throw new Exception(String.Format("Concrete model type {0} not found", concreteTypeResult.AttemptedValue));

                var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(() => instance, type);
                return instance;
            }
            else
            {
                return Activator.CreateInstance(modelType);
            }
        }
    }
```

Now all that left is to add "Type" property to each asset object:

```
            $(pledge.Assets).each(function () {

                this.Type = (typeof this.CityId !== 'undefined') ? 'RealEstateAsset' : 'TransportationAsset';

            });





            var ajaxOptions = {
                type: 'post',
                url: 'Home/TryInsertPledge',
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8;",
                data: JSON.stringify({ pledge: pledge }),
                success: function (data) {

                       alert('success');
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert(xhr.respnseText);
                }
            };
            $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

And the Assets got to server correctly...
Thank you again maciejlis

Comment: Do some refactoring on your method, please implement abstract factory patten, will ya?